# selenium phantomJS states 'element is not visible' but works fine in firefox

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to input a zipcode into a store website, and this works fine when I use webdriver.firefox() but does not work with PhantomJS. Instead I get an error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'SL-map-search'"
```

This is the fairly simple code I'm using to generate the request. The set_window_size is only being used because other similar questions have suggested that this might fix the issue (it didn't).

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
# get address
driver.set_window_size(1920,1080)
driver.get("http://www.lowes.com/StoreLocatorDisplayView")

# select zipcode
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'SL-map-search')
element.send_keys(zipcode)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'SL-map-search-submit').click()
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this in Chrome? PhantomJS uses the same JS engine as Chrome. Which version of PhantomJS are you using? Or are you using GhostDriver? Also, what language is this; perhaps add the tag.

Comment: I'm using phantomjs v 2.0.0. I don't think I'm using ghostdriver. I'll check chrome!

Comment: It works with chrome, so I guess it just doesn't work with PhantomJS - any suggestions on how I should proceed?

Comment: Add waits. Start with a dumb `Thread.sleep()` (still don't know what language you are using!) and see if that changes anything. If yes, then start playing around with proper Selenium waits.

Answer (score 1):

[Wait for the element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to be present:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "SL-map-search"))
)
element.send_keys(zipcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error was fixed when I upgraded to El Capitan.